# PHP filter_input not working

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that shows some server variables, the code is as following :

```
<?php
$FILTEREDHOST = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,'HTTP_HOST');
$FILTEREDSELF = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,'PHP_SELF');

$SERVERHOST = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$SERVERSELF = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

var_dump($FILTEREDHOST);
echo "</br>";
var_dump($FILTEREDSELF);
echo "</br>";
var_dump($SERVERHOST);
echo "</br>";
var_dump($SERVERSELF);
```

The result I get is :

```
NULL
string(9) "/test.php"
string(17) "www.mysite.com"
string(9) "/test.php"
```

Why  `$FILTEREDHOST` is returning `NULL` ?

My PHP version is 5.5.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP_HOST is not set if the browser didn't send it.

> 'HTTP_HOST'
>   Contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: why the browser sent it here :$SERVERHOST = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];  ??

Comment: I think it has to do with the strange side-effects of FastCGI. http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php#77307

Comment: Well, you might be right, I used the suggested function in that link and I see the the SERVER variable content and the HTTP_HOST is present.